# SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name like %value% IN (SELECT ...?

Tags: mysql, database

I need a query that looks like this for mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE column_name like %value% 
   IN (SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name like %second_value%)
```

How can i do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do with an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my understanding of your issue is correct, your query must be:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE column_name like '%value%' and column_name like '%second_value%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot select multiple columns from the nested `IN` query. You can only select one column.

I assume, you want to select `column_name` from the nested query.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name like '%value%' IN
(SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name like '%value%')
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @Jens Can you explain why?

Comment: First the %vaue% must be in single quotes ana also you can not have two operatorsfor one column.

Comment: The subquery is not redundant. There is a condition `other_column_name like %second_value%`

Comment: Sorry but this is such a terrible query. What does it mean to say  name `WHERE column_name like '%value%' IN` ?